# how to create boundly (only specific place) in autocomplete place googlemap api

Tags: java, android

i create a uber like app but problem is that pickuploaction is showing all place but my task is location showing only delhi places so how to handle this problem ? how to show only delhi places with google map api???? please anyone solve dis isssue?

```
private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, PlaceInfo placeInfo){
    Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

    mMap.clear();
    try {
        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .setCountry("au")
                .build();
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder
                (PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .setFilter(typeFilter)
                .build(PickUp_Location.this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_PLACE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException |
            GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(PickUp_Location.this));

    if(placeInfo != null){
        try{
            String snippet = "Address: " + placeInfo.getAddress() + "\n" +
                    "Phone Number: " + placeInfo.getPhoneNumber() + "\n" +
                    "Website: " + placeInfo.getWebsiteUri() + "\n" +
                    "Price Rating: " + placeInfo.getRating() + "\n";

            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(placeInfo.getName())
                    .snippet(snippet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can try as below with the help of "AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES" and setBoundsBias in PlaceAutocomplete intent:

you can change lat lng bounds as per your city area (i have added lat lng bound of delhi, india)

```
try {
                    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
                            .build();

                    Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                            .setFilter(typeFilter)
                            .setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(28.7041, 77.1025), new LatLng(28.7041, 77.1025)))
                            .build(TestatorDetailsActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_GLOBAL);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                }
```